# I forgot my icloud ID email is there anyway to retrieve it? i have my iphone box serial number?

Tags: mac

i dont know my ID email, all i have is an iphone box serial number in it, is their a way to retrieve it? all i want is the pictures at cloud please help

Comment: Are you logged into iCloud on your device? Or into the App Store?

Comment: as @nohillside said, one can enable mail in iCloud settings and then use mail to get email (doh)

Comment: @ankii if the user is logged into iCloud they can see their ID directly. But only „if“